# How to make logo effect revert back to "normal" when user scrolls back to the top of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Still needing help with this.  The answers I've received so far have not worked, though I do appreciate them.

I've got logo 1 in my header fading out on scroll down as logo 2 fades in.  I would like the header to return back to "normal" and logo 1 to be displayed (fading back in) when the user scrolls back to the top of the page. I'm a novice and have little knowledge of js. I've researched various ways to do this but can't figure out how to edit my current code to create this new effect ... without screwing everything up.   I appreciate the help.

```
 <header>
                <div id="nav" class="navbar">
                    <div id="nav_left">
                        <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
                        <a href="services.html">SERVICES</a>
                        <a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
                    </div>
                    <a href="index.html" id="logo" class="Claire_logo">
                        <img src="images/logo_6_small.png" alt="logo2" id="logo_Claire" class="logo_main"
                            style="display:none" />
                        <img src="images/logo_bluebird_90_cc.png" alt="logo1" id="logo_Claire_blue" class="logo" />
                    </a>
                    <div id="nav_right">
                        <a href="blog.html">BLOG</a>
                        <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
                        <a href="contact.html">GET IN TOUCH</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
```

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll > 70) {
          $('#logo_Claire_blue').fadeOut(800);

          setTimeout(function() {
            $('#logo_Claire').fadeIn(800);
          }, 800)
        };
      });
    });
```

Comment: Put code for logo1 in else.

Comment: @RamRatanBairar.  I'm not sure what you mean.  Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the else condition and revert the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scroll > 70) {
        $('#logo_Claire_blue').fadeOut(800);
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('#logo_Claire').fadeIn(800);
        }, 800)
      } else {
        $('#logo_Claire_blue').fadeIn(800);
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('#logo_Claire').fadeOut(800);
        }, 800)
      }
    });
});
```

**Update:**

Try like this in else condition

```
$('#logo_Claire_blue').fadeIn(800);
$('#logo_Claire').fadeOut(800);
```

Comment: This is better.  However, when you scroll back to the top both logos are appearing side by side for a second. Then logo 2 disappears and logo 1 moves over to the center.  Do you know why this is occuring?

Comment: instead of fadeOut() use hide() in else condition that will instantly hide that logo2

Comment: That changes things a bit but both logos still appear briefly once you return to the top of the page.

Comment: have you removed that timeout in your else condition? if not, remove that timeout and try

Comment: I have removed it. Now both logos appear permanently in the header when you scroll back to the top.

Comment: I tried the updated code you provided in the else condition.  This causes both logos to be displayed in the header on scroll up. Thank you for offering another suggestion though. I appreciate you trying to help

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                            $(window).scroll(function() {
                                if ($(document).scrollTop() < 8) {
                                    $('nav').addClass('transparent');
                                    $('.image1').show();
                                    $('.image2').hide();
                                } else {
                                    $('nav').removeClass('transparent').css('color: black');
                                    $('.image2').show();
                                    $('.image1').hide();
                                }
                            });
                        });
```

Comment: This does bring back logo 1 when user scrolls back to the top but it eliminates my fade in/out effect of the logos that I want to keep.  I need to somehow implement what you've given me with the code I already have ... so I maintain the smooth fade in/out effect and still return to logo 1 when returning to top of page.

Comment: my understanding is you are using two logos right,,

Answer (score 0):

The Html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<header>
  <div class="lrg-logo">Your Logo</div>
</header>
</div>
```

The CSS Style:

```
.wrapper {
  height: 2000px;
  position: relative;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.lrg-logo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/fff');
}

.sml-logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300');
}
```

The Js Part:

```
$(function () {
    var logo = $(".lrg-logo"); $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 500) {
            if (!logo.hasClass("sml-logo")) {
                logo.hide();
                logo.removeClass('lrg-logo').addClass("sml-logo").fadeIn("slow");
            }
        } else {
            if (!logo.hasClass("lrg-logo")) {
                logo.hide();
                logo.removeClass("sml-logo").addClass('lrg-logo').fadeIn("slow");
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Please let me know if this works, thanks.

Comment: This eliminates the smooth, slow transition between logos with the fade-in and fade-out effects I have already created.  And for some reason it's not switching the logos ..  Logo 1 is just quickly disappearing (fast fade) on scroll and then immediately reappearing.  I appreciate you trying to help though